# GWT: How to send POST cross domain requests with JSON

Tags: java, gwt, jsonp, http-post

As its Javadocs suggest, the [JsonpRequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/index.html?com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) can only send GET requests. I need to send POST requests using the same method (for cross domain requests using JSON). 
Does anybody know any working solution? I could not find any starting point on the web.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JSONP to do a POST - all it does is inserting a `<script src="...">` tag, and the browser fires off a GET request.

Maybe what you're looking for is [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/), but that's only supported by FF 3.5, IE 8 and Safari 4 and newer. And the server must support it, too.

Otherwise, you'll have to proxy from your server to the other domain.

Comment: thanks, your suggestions look promising. but due to limited time to this task, I have decided to keep using GET for now.

Comment: You forgot to mention Chrome 3 or newer. In case it helps, I've updated the CORS Wikipedia article with more detailed information on browser support that I gathered a few days ago.

Answer (score 4):

The [Google APIs Library for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/) solves this problem (to send cross-domain GWT-RPC calls) by using the [Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) project's [gadgets.rpc](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/docs/0.7/reference/gadgets.rpc.html) functionality to send a cross-frame message to an `iframe` in the page pointing to a page on the server you're trying to communicate with.  That `iframe` is the one that makes the request, and when it receives a response, it sends another cross-frame message back.

This is wrapped up in [`GadgetsRequestBuilder`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/gadgets/gadgets/src/com/google/gwt/gadgets/client/gwtrpc/GadgetsRequestBuilder.java).

It should be fairly straightforward to extend this functionality to make regular XHR requests (with a POST method) instead of GWT-RPC requests.

Comment: thanks for your suggest, but due to limited time to this task, I have decided to keep using GET for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and I had to implement a bit of a wacky scheme in order to get it to work. Luckily, I control both the server and client.

The POST call defines a url parameter called 'src' that contains some random string. When I POST to the server, the data goes to the server, but I am not able to get the response.

What happens is behind the scenes the server caches the POST response with that 'src' key in a weak cache.

I then do a JSONP get call immediately after the POST finishes with that same 'src' key, and it fetches the result.

It isn't pretty, but it works.